# In Nagios is check_interval used with passive alerts?

Tags: nagios, passive

I have a service that sends only passive alerts to a Nagios server; there are no active alerts set up in Nagios for this service. Here is one of the passive alerts:

```
define service {
    use                     default-template
    hostgroup_name          simple-servers-hostgroup
    service_description     service_alive
    active_checks_enabled   0 
    passive_checks_enabled  1 
    check_freshness         1 
    freshness_threshold     900  ; 15 min threshold
    check_command           check_freshness_critical
    check_interval          5                                                                                                     
    retry_interval          2                                                                                                      
    max_check_attempts      3    
}
```

Is the `check_interval` parameter used with passive alerts? If so, how does it work with the `freshness_threshold`?

Comment: No, `check_interval` is not used for passive checks.